# Summing with LEFT function, ignoring blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct, nonblank

I have a range that contains three digits-some text and there are some blank cells therefore receiving below message on image when I enter this formula:

=SUMPRODUCT(--LEFT(C12:C22;3))

[image]

Formula works just fine when I only select non-blank cells. Nonetheless, I would like it to contain blank cells as well.

I don't necessarily need sumproduct since I dont have other column, so I'm open to any solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--("0"&LEFT(C12:C22;3)))
```

Comment: clever. I was thinking in the direction Ike did

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

Any Excel-Version:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--IF(C12:C22<>"",LEFT(C12:C22,3),0))`

Excel 365 using `Filter`:

```vb
=LET(d,C12:C22,
dWithoutEmpty,FILTER(d,d<>""),
SUM(--LEFT(dWithoutEmpty,3)))
```